# Yii2 - Session Waste After Redirect Login To Index Page

Tags: php, yii2

I have a problem with logging in Yii2.
I created a database with table named `users` and corresponding model `Users` using Gii.

I also changed `config/web.php` file:

```
'user' => [
    'identityClass' => 'app\models\Users',
    'enableAutoLogin' => true,
],
```

Here is my `app\models\Users`:

```
namespace app\models;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "users".
 *
 * @property integer $id
 * @property string $username
 * @property string $email
 * @property string $password
 */
class Users extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord implements \yii\web\IdentityInterface {

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName() {
        return 'users';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules() {
        return [
            [['username', 'email', 'password'], 'required'],
            [['username', 'email'], 'string', 'max' => 200],
            [['password'], 'string', 'max' => 300],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels() {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'username' => 'Username',
            'email' => 'Email',
            'password' => 'Password',
        ];
    }

    public static function findByUsername($username) {
        return self::findOne(['username' => $username]);
    }

    public function validatePassword($password) {
        return $this->password === $password;
    }

    public static function findIdentity($id) {
        $user = Users::findOne($id);
        if (count($user)) {
            return new static($user);
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null) {
        throw new \yii\base\NotSupportedException();
    }

    public function getAuthKey() {
        return $this->authKey;
    }

    public function validateAuthKey($authKey) {
        return $this->authKey === $authKey;
    }

    public function getId() {
        return $this->username;
    }
}
```

And here is my `SiteController` code in `actionLogin()`:

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        return $this->goHome();
    }

    $model = new LoginForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
        //var_dump(Yii::$app->user->identity);

        return $this->goBack();
        //return $this->render('login',Yii::$app->user->identity);
    }
    return $this->render('login', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

This is when redirect to home not show username and logout but when I use:

```
var_dump(Yii::$app->user->identity);
```

It shows all variable set true.

and here is loginform

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

/**
 * LoginForm is the model behind the login form.
 *
 * @property User|null $user This property is read-only.
 *
 */
class LoginForm extends Model
{
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe = true;

    private $_user = false;


    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['username', 'password'], 'required'],
            // rememberMe must be a boolean value
            ['rememberMe', 'boolean'],
            // password is validated by validatePassword()
            ['password', 'validatePassword'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Validates the password.
     * This method serves as the inline validation for password.
     *
     * @param string $attribute the attribute currently being validated
     * @param array $params the additional name-value pairs given in the rule
     */
    public function validatePassword($attribute, $params)
    {
        if (!$this->hasErrors()) {
            $user = $this->getUser();

            if (!$user || !$user->validatePassword($this->password)) {
                $this->addError($attribute, 'Incorrect username or password.');
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Logs in a user using the provided username and password.
     * @return bool whether the user is logged in successfully
     */
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 20);
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by [[username]]
     *
     * @return User|null
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        if ($this->_user === false) {
            $this->_user = Users::findByUsername($this->username);
        }

        return $this->_user;
    }
}
```

I created same program before and works fine. Where is the problem?
Any way to solve this?

Comment: What is in your `LoginForm`?

Comment: add the view where you are trying to show the username and logout link

Comment: @rob006  i added loginform to my post

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam tnx..where can i add this?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam in view\layout logout is defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `findIdentity()` method looks suspicious. You're using `username` as identity ID, but `Users::findOne($id)` will search by `id` column in `users` table. Try change it to:

```
public static function findIdentity($id) {
    return static::findByUsername($id);
}
```

Comment: thanks dude that works true...but i have question..i programmed a simillar web app and that worked with that...any difference between them?

Comment: I don't know your apps , so I'm unable to answer this question. The best way would be compare these two apps and find the difference.